# Python print function does not return the updated variable

Tags: python, printing, assign

I am learning Python and something related to `print` confused me. Not sure if someone asked the same question already:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x, y = x + 2, print(x)
1
```

I understand that output `1` is the side effect of Python's `print` function. But why doesn't it print `3`? I was expecting `3` because `x` is updated in the second line? I was thinking it is equivalent to (apparently, wrong):

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x = x + 2
>>> x
3
>>> y = print(x)
3
```

I would like to understand the logic behind this `print` function. Why doesn't it print the updated `x` value?

I am new to the programming world, so any insight is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything on the right-hand side is evaluated first. You can use the python byte-code dissasembler to see what is happening:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('x, y = x + 2, print(x)')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 LOAD_NAME                1 (print)
              8 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 ROT_TWO
             14 STORE_NAME               0 (x)
             16 STORE_NAME               2 (y)
             18 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

Note, `x + 2` and `print(x)` are evaluated *first*. The BINARY_ADD and CALL_FUNCTION occur before the two `STORE_NAME`s.

Note, you can think of this as the equivalent of building a tuple first,

```
temp = (x + 2, print(x))
```

and then simply:

```
x, y = temp
```

However, note, according to the dissasembler, no actual intermediate tuple is created. The call stack is used to store the intermediate values. This is a compiler optimization. However, the optimization does not work for tuples greater than length 3, so using 4, you'll see an intermediate tuple is create:

```
>>> dis.dis('foo, bar, baz, bang  = bang, baz, bar, foo')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (bang)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (baz)
              4 LOAD_NAME                2 (bar)
              6 LOAD_NAME                3 (foo)
              8 BUILD_TUPLE              4
             10 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          4
             12 STORE_NAME               3 (foo)
             14 STORE_NAME               2 (bar)
             16 STORE_NAME               1 (baz)
             18 STORE_NAME               0 (bang)
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

Note the `BUILD_TUPLE` and `UNPACK_SEQUENCE`, which is the general way that unpacking works in Python. It's just the compiler optimizes the common cases of two-or-three with the ROT_TWO and ROT_THREE op codes.

Note, since the right-hand side is evaluate first, this allows for the Python swap idiom to work!

```
x, y = y, x
```

If this were equivalent to:

```
x = y
y = x
```

You would lose the value for x instead of swapping!

Comment: wow, your explanation has the depth. I never heard of this byte-code dissasembler but it is a very helpful tool to understand Python's underlying activities. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x, y = x + 2, print(x)
1
```

`print(x)`
outputs the value stored in x assigned by you

for printing 3 you need to 
print(y)

as y stores the value of x+2

Answer (score 0):

Because python processes line by line (meaning after the whole line, process it), so `x` haven't updated yet, so that's why it's not working as expected, but if you do `;` (semicolon) it will work, because semicolon `;` is basically a separator of lines too, so basically everything after `;` is taken as a new line, demo:

```
>>> x=1
>>> x, y = x + 2,0; print(x)
3
>>>
```

Issue is that `y` is gonna be 0:

```
>>> y
0
>>>
```

Because i do so, you have to have a value,

But if you care, delete it:

```
>>> x=1
>>> x, y = x + 2,0; print(x)
3
>>> del y
>>> y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    y
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value on the left hand side of an assignment doesn't get updated until everything on the right hand side is done processing.That's why X is not yet 3 when you try to print it on the right hand side.